# Expanding pop up window upon button press Android

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm still new to Android development. I kinda stuck trying to figure out how to dynamically change the pop-up window height when a user presses a button in the pop-up window? The expanded pop-up window (with simple animation) will reveal a drop-down list for user selection.

I'm thinking of a two layer pop-up window with invisible drop-down list. So once the pop-up window is expanded, it will reveal the drop-down list. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly then what you want to do is that first time dropdown will be invisible and when button is pressed in popup then you want to show that dropdown to visible. isn't it??

so you can just try first of all is make DropDownlist as ViewGone in visibility and when button is pressed then make its visibility to visible mode.

i think that should work for you.

Comment: Yes the drop-down list should be invisible. But there are other related items as well such as "Save" and "Cancel" button, which will be revealed only in the expanded layout. How to expand the pop-up window dynamically?

Comment: is there any button click for expanding in popup view??

Comment: Yes there is. Just a normal button click and the Pop-up window will expand its height slightly to show the drop-down list.

Comment: Then its perfect. on click of button set visibility to visible of buttons and dropdown.

Comment: Erm I dun think u get what I meant. The pop-up window size is initially small enough to fit one textview and an imagebutton. When the imagebutton is clicked, the pop-up window will expand its height (arnd 30dp) and reveal the drop-down list. I need to know how to change the height of the pop-up window dynamically. 

Setting visibility is easy. Changing the height of the pop-up window dynamically is something else.

Comment: you don't have to do anything. if your main layout height is set to wrap content then you just need to set visibility of buttons and drop down as view.gone. it will make your pop up as small as without dropdown and button. when you click on button of expand it will set visibility to visible and your pop will be expanded automatically.

Comment: View.Gone will not take its space in View. so it won't be considered while rendering it. so just visibility will do for you. just try it. and tell me.

Comment: I have two frame layouts in my pop-up window. I set both frame layouts height to "wrap content". The view is gone for the drop-down list but the pop-up window doesn't resize. Any idea?

Comment: if you have used frame for dropdown then you need to do this for frame as well... try to do that...

Comment: Done that already but there is no difference. I doubt that view.Gone will cause the frame to resize though. What about changing the frame size height programmatically? Upon button click, expand the frame height?

Comment: yes you can do that. i had same thing in my app. on radio button check event i wanted to open listview below that radiogroup. and View.gone has worked like a charm in app.

Comment: Hi Armaan, is there anyway I can send my code to you for reference? I did what u told me but nothing happened :(

Comment: Thank you Armaan Stranger. 

I changed my main layout to "Linear Layout" implemented with table rows to hold the buttons and the drop-down list. Relative & Frame Layout for the main layout didn't work for me though.

Comment: Relative may also work but Linear Layout will be easy to handle thats why we have used it.